# Permissions to execute System.abortJob() method

Tags: apex, permissions, scheduled-apex

What permissions does user need to call `System.abortJob()` in Apex?

When the method is called this error is displayed:

> System.SecurityException: Insufficient Privileges.

Thanks.

Comment: Standard System Admin Profile should do it.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:** I just confirmed with testing that the "Modify All Data" system permission is what is required to use the System.abortJob() method. Unfortunately, there isn't any specific permission to allow this by itself.

Comment: Thank you. So, if I got it, when the user is not a System Administrator is not possible to execute System.abortJob() method and there is no permission to it.
Are there difference between a customer org and a development org to it? In the customer org, can another users execute the method through a managed class?