# How to abort current scheduled job?

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

I would like to schedule a job to run once in 15 minutes time.

According to this article:

- [Run Scheduled Apex job once](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000314061&type=1&mode=1)

I need to add some code to the `finish` method:

```
public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {

    AsyncApexJob a = [SELECT Id FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id = :context.getJobId()];

    System.abortJob(a.id);
}
```

It seems to me that the `SOQL` query is not required and that I could just run this line:

```
System.abortJob(context.getJobId());
```

Is that true? or am I missing something?

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm?search_text=abortJob) for method `abortJob` says:

> The jobId is the ID associated with either AsyncApexJob or CronTrigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use what you have mentioned:

```
System.abortJob(context.getJobId());
```

The other KB article [Run Scheduled Apex job once](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000314061&type=1&mode=1) may have *overdone* things there. But `getJobId()` necessarily returns the `AsyncApexJob`'s Id which can be used to abort the job. Below is an excerpt from [Using Batch Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm#getJobId) as reference  (emphasis mine).

> Returns the ID of the `AsyncApexJob` object associated with this batch job as a string. Use this method to track the progress of records in the batch job. **You can also use this ID with the `System.abortJob` method**.

Comment: Note that abortion can only be called by a user with the appropriate permission (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9013/permissions-to-execute-system-abortjob-method) which basically means a sys admin. So don't try to use this in code that can be run by other types of user.